# Create Homepage Template with various sections in magento 2

Tags: theme, template, magento2.2

I'd like to create a custom homepage template with different sections. I already declared the page layout in layouts.xml inside my theme folder

```
<layout id="start_page">
    <label translate="true">Startseite</label>
</layout>
```

After this I created a start_page.xml inside the page_layout folder

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
<update handle="1column"/>
<referenceContainer name="main.content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="start_page" template="Magento_Theme::start_page.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

I also created a start_page.phtml inside my templates folder. My sample output works already.

I'm no struggling with the implementation and I want to ask you how the best practice is to create different sections like category cutouts with product teasers or slideshows. I drew the sections for you in the example below

[image]

- **purple:** product category with products, the backend user should be able to set the alignment
- **blue:** product category with products; similar to purple but theres a slideshow and a background image possible
- **red:**  product category with products; not similar to purple; product tiles html will be different because of some extra features
- **green:**  page links; the backend user is able to select some normal pages which will be displayed as tiles with a background image

How is it recommended to start the implementation? How can I structure it well? How can the administrator manage?

It would be a big help for me if you could answer me these questions. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a single question you should hire Magento freelancer. You can hire me if you want. (Bhai ana to paisa thai).